# I made a click counter but it doesnt show a secret message when reached a certain number

Tags: javascript, html

When the click counter reaches 69 it should display "Nice" in the h4 bellow but i can only make it to show the else "error" message (the else message should be in blank " " but for testing i put a message)

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Clic to count +1 </button>
<h4 id="demo"> 0 </h4>
<h4 id="secret"> </h4>
```

Javascript

```
const add = (function () {
  let counter = 60;
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter;}
} )();

function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
  
  if (add == 69){
  document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = "Nice";
}else{
  document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = "error";
 }

}
```

The initial value of counter is 60 to make it faster to test

Comment: const count = add();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = count;
if (count === 69) {...}

Comment: add is a function, when you call the function `add()` it returns the counter, so you need a variable to store the value returned by add

Comment: `When the click counter reaches 69 it should display "Nice"` of course it should :p

Comment: and I am just amazed by the choice of number 69 :)

Comment: Note the [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) is usually used rather than `variable += 1`. For example: `function () { return ++counter; }`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not bad at all. You'll need to store the value of the counter outside of the function, otherwise it will be reset to 60 each time the button is clicked. Furthermore i'd simplify the function hell. You variable `add` contains a function which returns a function. This also works, but is a pain to read. Always try to focus on less complexity but more readability.

```js
let counter = 60;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter

function add() {
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}

function myFunction(){
  let counterAfterAdding = add();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counterAfterAdding

  if (counterAfterAdding === 69){
    document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = "Nice";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = "error";
  }

}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Click to count +1 </button>
<h4 id="demo"> 0 </h4>
<h4 id="secret"> </h4>
```

Comment: code not working,only error message and the counetr doesnt go up

Comment: The code did work. I wasn't aware that you wanted to have the counter displayed in your `.demo` headline but the logic worked. After clicking the button 9 times 'Nice' was displayed. Changed the code fragment to always display the counter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const add = (function() {
  let counter = 60;
  return function() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
  }
})();

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
  if (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML == 69) {
    document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = "Nice";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = "error";
  }

}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Clic to count +1 </button>
<h4 id="demo"> 0 </h4>
<h4 id="secret"> </h4>
```

`add` is a function, when you call it, it make `counter += 1` again. So instead, also avoid making a global variable as Amir Saleem suggested, you can directly compare what's in the element's content, or make a variable count like Amir Saleem's post.

Comment: This is an unnecessarily complex implementation. The OP is using a closure function to avoid the use of a global variable and here you are using the value returned by the closure in a global variable

Answer (score 0):

What is add?

add is a function, so when you do `console.log(add)` it will display something like `ƒ () {counter += 1; return counter;}`

since `add` is a function it can never be equal to `69`.

When you call `add` it updates the counter value and returns the same. You can store the value returned by the function `add`

`const newCounter = add(); // whatever is returned by the add is stored in this variable`

You can now do the comparison with the value stored in a `newCounter` variable like `newCounter === 69`

Here is the updated snippet:

```js
 const add = (function () {
  let counter = 60;
  return function () {counter += 1; return counter;}
} )();

function myFunction(){
  const count = add();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = count;
  
  if (count == 69){
   document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = "Nice";
  } else{
   document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = "error";
  }

}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Click to count +1 </button>
<h4 id="demo"> 0 </h4>
<h4 id="secret"> </h4>
```

Comment: Why would you want the add function to return another function? Seems unnecessarily complex to me.
You should stick with one function syntax instead. Anonymus/function expressions are not giving any benefit here.

Comment: @jdickel That is a Closure function. That is used to avoid global variables. I recommend you do a quick google search on Closures in Javascript